# How to read data from file to UChar vector correctly without type casting?

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream

I have a file, that contains unicode characters,  and this code read them to std::vector:

```
std::ifstream file("/home/myuser/fileWithUChar.txt", std::ifstream::binary);

file.seekg(0, file.end);
unsigned long sizeOfFile = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, file.beg);

std::vector<UChar> unicodeSymbols; //sizeof(UChar) = 2
unicodeSymbols.resize(sizeOfFile / sizeof(UChar));

file.read((char*)unicodeSymbols.data(), sizeOfFile);
```

My question is: How can I avoid this casting in last string ? I don't really want to use reinterpret_cast. Is there a better way to read bytes from file ?

Comment: Firstly, "Unicode" is **not** an encoding for text files. It is a standard which also defines several encodings. So, first task is to find out which encoding is used. Then, do a simple websearch for "C++ read file with encoding <ENCODING>" and digest the results you find there.

Comment: I really saved in file Unicode characters, for example, U+0046, so I need to read 2 bytes and push it to one element of std::vector<UChar>

Comment: Sorry, but the mere fact that you are talking about "Unicode characters" shows that you don't understand yet what an encoding is and what the Unicode standard is. As a hint, there are four encodings that use two bytes, UTF-16 and UCS2, both in little and big endian variants.

Comment: hey, I again explain - I write exactly Unicode characters, like U+0046, U+006F - without U+ of course. Like in this table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: @ASbggh You were given excellent pointers in the comments above. Do what you can to follow them.